# Can't initialize object of an inner class C++

Tags: c++

I have 2 classes, one nested inside of another:

```
class List {
private:
    class Node {
    public:
        Token data;
        Node* next;
        Node(const Token &dataItem, Node* nextptr);
    };
    Node* first;
    int length;
public:
    List();
    virtual ~List();
    void insert (const Token &t);
    Node* lookup(const Token &t) const;  
};
```

Class node has it's constructor:

```
List::Node::Node(const Token &dataItem, Node* nextptr): data(dataItem) {
        data = dataItem;
        next = nextptr;
    }
```

But when I try to initialize one of node in insert method, like this:

```
void List::insert (const Token &t){
if(first == NULL){
Node* node = new Node(t, nullptr); //PROGRAM DIES HERE
first = node;
cout<<"hey"<<endl;
}else{
    Node* isHere = lookup(t);
    //if not
    if(isHere == NULL){
        Node* temp = first;
                Node* node = new Node(t, NULL);
                while(true){
                    if((temp->data.getName().compare(t.getName())>0)or(temp->next==NULL)){
                        Node* temp2 = temp->next;
                        temp->next = node;
                        node->next = temp2;
                        break;
                    }
                    temp=temp->next;
                }
    }
    //if node exists
    else{
        cout<<"node exists"<<endl;
        isHere->data.newEntry(t.getLines()[0]);
        cout<<"node out"<<endl;

    }
  }
}
```

Lookup method:

```
List::Node* List::lookup(const Token &t) const{
    if(first == NULL)
        return first;
    if(first->data.isEquivalent(t))
                   return first;
       cout<<"finished coparre"<<endl;

    Node* temp = first;
       while(temp->next != NULL){
           cout<<"in da loop"<<endl;
           temp = temp->next;
           if(temp->data.isEquivalent(t))
               return temp;
       }
       return NULL;
}
```

Program just silently dies at the line I commented. What do I do wrong here?
Ok, here is a token. I dont think there is problem there, but it was requested too, so here is the source:
Token header:

```
class Token {
    std::string name; // token name
    int frequency;//frequency
    Vector lines;//lines where the token is present

public:
    //explanations for the methods in the Token.cpp
    Token(std::string tokenname, int linenumber);
    virtual ~Token();
    void newEntry(int &linenumber);
    Vector getLines() const;
    std::string getName() const;
    int getFrequency() const;
    const bool isEquivalent(const Token &t);
```

;

Token methods:

```
Token::Token(string tokenname, int linenumber) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    name = tokenname;
    frequency=1;
    lines.push_back(linenumber);
}
void Token::newEntry(int &linenumber){
    cout<< "enter new entry"<<endl;

    frequency++;
    lines.push_back(linenumber);
    cout<< "finish  new entry"<<endl;

}

std::string Token::getName() const{
    return name;
}

const bool Token::isEquivalent(const Token &t){
    if(t.getName().compare(name)==0)
    return true;
    else
        return false;
}

Vector Token::getLines() const{
    return lines;
}
```

Comment: What's `Token`? In particular what do its copy constructor and assignment operator look like?

Comment: ok, i will upload token, although i dont feel like it is guilty here. but who knows>_<

Comment: I suspect the token you are passing to insert is a dangling reference but you would need to post the code where you call insert for me to see. A dangling reference is when you have a reference to an object which no longer exists, fyi.

Comment: how are you calling `insert`?

Comment: This is how
void TokenDB::putIn(std::string name, int linenumber){
  int index = Utils::getPosition(name.at(0));
  Token newToken(name, linenumber);
  database[index].insert(newToken);}

Comment: Change that to `Token t;` and `database[index].insert(t)`. And using smart pointers is always better than using `new`

Comment: newToken is not new, it is the name of a token object:/ I can rename it to t, although it wont change much. Token t(name, linenumber)

Comment: Remove everything not necessary to reproduce the problem but keep it complete so that others can reproduce it. Your code is neither minimal nor complete.

Comment: that should be enough to reproduce i think.

Comment: What is Vector? Which optimization level did you use and how did you determine, that it is exactly this line?

Comment: you better check stack trace.

Comment: something in command line says:  double free or corruption(fasttop)

Comment: Your code doesn't have a `main()`, so it can't be enough. Further, if you want people to actually reproduce it, provide it so that you can just copy'n'paste it into a file and compile it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an error in the constructor:

```
List::Node::Node(const Token &dataItem, Node* nextptr): data(dataItem) {
        data = dataItem;
        next = nextptr;
    }
```

We also need to pass a pointer to make it work correct

```
List::Node::Node(const Token &dataItem, Node* nextptr): data(dataItem), next(nextptr){}
```